# Degraded WordPress admin dashboard performance

Tags: wp-admin, performance

My daughter's school asked me to take a look into "why their site is suddenly very slow". It runs on one.com/Wordpress, of which I know almost nothing, my own sites are VPS/Django-based. But what became immediately clear is that the site itself works perfectly fine, however the Wordpress admin interface is not just slow—it takes dozens and hundreds of seconds to load any page (I only tested a few).

Example (using Chrome's network tool):

- Main school page: loaded in <1 s.
- WP admin panel (after entering login/password in the login page): loaded in 2.2 min!

According to the school administration, a week ago the admin panel worked fine, the problem appeared "suddenly" this week. No new plugins are known to be installed or settings changed.

I wonder if this is something known in the Wordpress world, or if someone could suggest hints how to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin if you can.

This is the most powerful WordPress debug plugin that can show all the issues including what is taking how much time to load.

[image: Query Monitor Screenshot]

Once installed and activated, this plugin shows on the top bar, both on the front end and the admin panel. Once you click the bar, it can show you all sorts of necessary information to debug possible issues.

---

You may also want to read the documentation about [debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, install 2 plugins:

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-functions-time/

This will show you the slowest filters and actions in Backend. With this you can easily detect what plugin is taking a lot of time to complete and disable / investigate it.